# Software to plot complex numbers in Argand diagram

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm looking for a software or an online resources that allows me to plot complex number inequalities in the Argand diagram similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065679/greatest-and-least-values-of-arg-z-for-points-lying-in-a-region).

Please, any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Arif

Comment: See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you translate the inequalities to what they say about $x$ and $y$, you can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x-1)%5E2+%2B+(y-3)%5E2%3C%3D1+and+y+%3E%3D+3).  I don't know if you can use Wolfram Alpha directly: if you give it an inequality involving complex numbers, it just says "Inequalities are not well-defined in the complex plane".

In Maple you could use something like this:

```
 ineqs:= evalc(subs(z=x+I*y, {abs(z+1-3*I) <= 1, Im(z) >= 3}));
 plots[inequal](ineqs, x=-4..4,y=-4..4);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I'm looking for a graphing package that plot complex number inequalities  and gives result in the form similar to my diagram [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065679/greatest-and-least-values-of-arg-z-for-points-lying-in-a-region), that helps find the  least and greatest value of $arg(z)$    and other similar questions.