# Plotting Complex Sets in a Research Paper

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am meant to "sketch" the set $|z - 1 + i| \leq 3$ for my Complex Analysis homework. I am able to draw this set by hand, so my question isn't about that! Rather, I would like to know how a professional mathematician would generate such an image if he or she were submitting the image as part of a journal article. What program/software/code would he or she use?...all I need is a direction to head in!

(For context: I get extra credit in the class for submitting my homework typed out in Latex. And for this question, I'm sure I could just leave a blank space and hand draw the diagram. I also found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082934/software-to-plot-complex-numbers-in-argand-diagram), which is kind of a hacker way to generate such diagrams. But my aspiration is to become a mathematician, and so I wanna know how a real mathematician would make such a diagram! Thanks in advance!)

Comment: This is probably more suited for the TeX StackExchange. But I can recommend using **TikZ** (a package for producing graphics by writing commands directly in the LaTeX file).

Comment: You might be interested in this specific example: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/complex-plane/  ;-)

Comment: It is not "unprofessional" to import external graphics in $\LaTeX$. That's what the graphicx package is for.

Comment: Thank you both. @Hans Lundmark, I literally was not aware of the TeX stack exchange until I read your response moments ago. Clearly you are correct that this is a question for that group! I am very grateful for the direction.

Comment: @Christoph, this is good information. I suspected that the correct thing to do would be to import a graphic into LaTex. I will definitely have to investigate the graphicx package. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another tool that can be incorporated into LaTeX documents: [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/). It's a programming language, so there's a learning curve there. On the plus side, it comes standard with TeX distributions, and the usual editors can easily be configured to run Asymptote code in the same .tex file as everything else.

Drawing circles is in the base capabilities of Asymptote even before importing any of the standard libraries.